# Vue js post request form | vue js 2

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I am trying to post my form using axios. But it's not working( I am not able to get the data to my backend). And sorry to say that I am new in vue js.

This is what I am doing:

**Template:**

```
<b-form @submit.prevent="create" method="post">

            <b-form-group>
                <b-col sm="1">
                    <label :for="`type-text`">Title:</label>
                </b-col>
                <b-col sm="9">
                    <b-form-input :id="`type-text`" :type="text" v-model="article.title" required></b-form-input>
                </b-col>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-form-group>
                <b-col sm="1">
                    <label for="textarea-no-auto-shrink">Content:</label>
                </b-col>
                <b-col sm="9">
                    <b-form-textarea id="textarea-no-auto-shrink" placeholder="write something..." v-model="article.content" required rows="3" max-rows="3"></b-form-textarea>
                </b-col>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-form-group>
                <b-col sm="1">
                </b-col>
                <b-button type="submit" class="mt-2 ml-3">Submit</b-button>
            </b-form-group>

        </b-form>
```

**script**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'List',
    props: {},

    data() {
        return {
            articles: [],
            article: {
                title: '',
                content: '',
            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
            .then(response => (this.articles = response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },

    methods: {
        create() {
                axios
                    .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
                        this.article
                    )
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$router.push('/home');
                        return response;
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

**Error :**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `403`
> (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

I work now in my project with *Vue.js* and *Node.js*. I'm going to show you my *post request*. It works fine. The architecture in the back-end is Model,Route,Controller

this is the *post request* in the front-end:

```
 handleSubmit() {
      const create = {
        name: this.name,
        description: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
      };
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/category", create)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(create);
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

this is post request handling in the back-end:

```
exports.storeCategory = async function (req, res) {
  const createCategory = new category({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
  });

  try {
    const savecategory = await createategory.save();

    res.send(create);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your axios request you didn't specify the right URL to post your request you just stopped on api `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` so specify the right backend URL to receive that request for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts`

```
        create() {
            axios
                .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts',
                    this.article
                )
                .then(response => {
                    this.$router.push('/home');
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async createSubCategory({ commit }, data) {
    commit("SET_STATE", {
      action: "loading",
      data: true,
    });
    try {
      const res = await this.$http.post("/category/sub", data);
      commit("SET_STATE", {
        action: "loading",
        data: false,
      });
      return {
        message: res.data.message,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      commit("SET_STATE", {
        action: "loading",
        data: false,
      });
      // Manage Error
      const { message } = getMessageFromError(error);
      return Promise.reject({
        message,
      });
    }
},
```

**On click save_changes function will be call and inside this function called some another action call and passed data in this function
**

```js
async save_changes() {
  if (!(await this.$validator.validate())) {
      return false;
  }
    try {
        const { message } = await this.createSubCategory({
          ...this.form,
        });
        this.$router.push({
          name: "category-list",
        });
        this.$vs.notify({
          title: "Success",
          text: message,
          iconPack: "feather",
          icon: "icon-alert-circle",
          color: "success",
        });
    } catch ({ message }) {
        this.$vs.notify({
          title: "Error",
          text: message,
          iconPack: "feather",
          icon: "icon-alert-circle",
          color: "danger",
        });
      }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your back-end recognizes the endpoint you are using for post request.
Maybe you want to hit something like 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts' ?

Also, the payload for axios should be an object with key-value pairs

```
 axios
                .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts',
                    {article: this.article}
                )
                .then(response => {
                    this.$router.push('/home');
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

Comment: Make sure you have the .htaccess enabled